# Get 1 minute interval from start and end field on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with information about a process which happens at different intervals of time.

I need to get information from this table and get the data (for instance, tons) every 1 minutes.

This is the data on the table, where is indicated the beggining and the end of each process, and I need to get all the information together and make a graph every 1 minutes.

```
starttime    endtime    status
0            1209       4
1209         1215       2
1215         1900       4
1900         3611       4
3611         5934       2
5934         6382       4
6382         13965      2
13965        15823      4
15823        22103      2
```

What I want is this:

```
time        status
00:01:00    4
00:02:00    4
00:03:00    2
```

(just an example)

How can I turn the time given between 2 fields into a single interval? (the time is in seconds on the table, and i need it into minutes)

Comment: You need a calendar table or a tally table. You need a table that already has a list of minutes in it, and you join that to your table using `BETWEEN`. It would also help to indicate what data type those times are because they'll might need to be converted to proper times.

Comment: How you converted starttime and endtime to minutes 00:01:00, Explain us in detail?

Comment: i havent yet, but what works for me is this:

ceiling(seconds/60)*60